# Check if customer attribute already exists

Tags: attributes, customer, magento-community

I have a custom module which is called on the `customer_save_observer_executed` event and specifically when a customer updates their details in their account page (name, password, email etc) I have added a custom attribute called display_name.

When a customer submits this form i need to check if the display_name currently exists for any other customer. If it doesn't then `setDisplayName(...)` else do nothing/display error message.

I was hoping to do this with this snippet:

```
$customer_check = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('display_name')
->addAttributeToFilter('display_name',$new_name)->load();

if ( is_object($customer_check) && count($customer_check) >= 2) {
    // dont allow - duplicate customer displayname
}
else {
    // allow update....
}
```

My current code in Model -> Observer.php

```
class xxxxxxx_Model_Observer
{
    public function xxxxxxxx(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        // to stop event being fired twice
        if(Mage::registry('customer_save_observer_executed')){
            return $this;
        }

        $postData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

        // if updating NOT a new customer
        if($customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer && !$customer->isObjectNew()) {

            // check display name is posted
            if(!empty($postData['display_name'])){

                $current_name = $customer->getDisplayName();
                $new_name = $postData['display_name'];

                // duplicate check
                $customer_check = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('display_name')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('display_name',$new_name)->load();

                if ( is_object($customer_check) && count($customer_check) >= 2) {
                    // dont allow - duplicate customer displayname
                }
                else {

                    if( $postData['display_name'] !== $current_name ) {
                        $customer->setDisplayName($postData['display_name']);
                    }

                }

            }

        }

        Mage::register('customer_save_observer_executed',true); 

    }
}
```

but this just updates the display_name even if i deliberately set it to a duplicate of another customers

**UPDATE**

Looking into this further it looks like the module function itself is not being run or nothing inside it is taking affect, as whatever i put in it doesn't work. It is infact the default behaviour that is setting the displayname not my module. My module is activated and my config file uses the `customer_save_commit_after` event as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <xxx_xxxxx>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </xxx_xxxxx>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <xxx_xxxxx>
                <class>xxx_xxxxx_Model</class>
            </xxx_xxxxx>
        </models>
        <events>
            <customer_save_commit_after>
                <observers>
                    <xxx_xxxxx>
                        <class>xxx_xxxxx/observer</class>
                        <method>xxxxxx</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </xxx_xxxxx>
                </observers>
            </customer_save_commit_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**Step1:** trigger an `event on basic of customer_save_before`

```
<global>
    <events>
        <customer_save_before>
            <observers>
                <stockalert>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>magento37890/observer</class>
                    <method>checkDisplay</method>
                </stockalert>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_before>
    </events>
</global>
```

**Step2:**

In `before  event` give  you `can  get customer  id` if `customer is old`,then  checking  `current value and past value  match  or not`.
If  not match then checking this `value exit in Rest of collection`. If `exit then send a flag (false)`  and

```
throw error   using throw Mage::exception
which prevent data save
```

.....

```
if($flagofmy==false){

                throw Mage::exception(
                    'Mage_Customer', Mage::helper('customer')->__('This customer lastname already exists'),
                    Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS
                );
}
```

**full Logic**

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento37890_Model_Observer
{
public function checkDisplay(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    $flagofmy=true;
    //eeeeee
    $customer=$observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
    Mage::log('My log entry'.$customer->getId(), null, 'Magento37890.log');
    /* if customer  is old customer */
    if($customer->getId()){
            if($customer->getOrigData('lastname')!=$customer->getData('lastname')){

            Mage::log($customer->getData('lastname').'My log entry'.$customer->getId(), null, 'Magento37890.log');

            $flagofmy=$this->HasLastName($customer->getData('lastname'));
            if($flagofmy==false){

                throw Mage::exception(
                    'Mage_Customer', Mage::helper('customer')->__('This customer lastname already exists'),
                    Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS
                );

                }
            }else{
                    Mage::log($customer->getData('lastname').' Step A _1'.$customer->getId(), null, 'Magento37890.log');

            }

    }else{
        /* New Customer */

            $flagofmy=$this->NewHasLastName($customer->getData('lastname'));

                throw Mage::exception(
                    'Mage_Customer', Mage::helper('customer')->__('This customer lastname already exists'),
                    Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS
                );

    }

}
protected function HasLastName($lastname){


 $customer_check = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('lastname',$lastname);

         if(count($customer_check)>0){
                return false;
         }  
         return true;     
}
}
```

**Note: I  have done basic of lastname field juts need to change field name to display_name**

Comment: Thanks for this. I have just edited my config and Observer files to match the above but i get this error message: `Fatal error: Call to a member function checkCustomerId() on a non-object in /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php on line 196`

Comment: My module still has the directory setup: `etc/config.xml` and `Model/Observer.php` as the only 2 files still - is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your observer to `customer_save_before`

```
 .....
     $new_name = $postData['display_name'];

    // if updating NOT a new customer
    if($customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer && !$customer->isObjectNew() && !empty($new_name)) {

        // duplicate check
        $customer_check = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                 ->getCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('display_name')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('neq' => $customer->getId()))
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('display_name',$new_name)->load();

        if ($customer_check->getSize() == 0) {
           $customer->setDisplayName($postData['display_name']);
        }
   }
```